# junit core java reverse string test cases

Tags: java, string, junit, reverse

can anyone please tell me how to write test case in the below code

```java
public static String reverseWord(String str) {   
    String a[] = str.split(" ");
    
    try {
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

I have written the below test case but it is failed

```java
@Test
public void testReverseWord() {
    assertEquals("world hello", Logic.reverseWord("hello world"));   
}
```

Comment: Your reverseWord method isn't changing the returned value `str`, instead of printing the array, create a new string instance and add it there

Comment: @Bahij.Mik I'm not getting it what are you saying, can you please tell me in the code?

Answer (score 2):

You return exactly the same String as you get as argument, changes that you are doing are printed to the console instead of being returned.

Try this code instead. I am creating StringBuilder (you can read more about it here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) which is used for String concatenation. Note that I am adding space only if it is not the last word - so that your returned String doesn't have space at the end. At the end by calling `toString()` on StringBuilder object I am returning new reversed String, exactly what you wanted.

```
public static String reverseWord(String str) {

    String a[] = str.split(" ");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {

        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            builder.append(a[i]);

            if (i != 0) {
                builder.append(" ");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test case is correct, but the method itself is wrong, you are splitting the string then just printing out values instead of creating a new string and concatenating those values there, so instead of `System.out.print(a[i] + " ");` introduce a new String outside the loop `String result = ""` and concatenate the values:

```
        String a[] = str.split(" ");
        String result = "";

        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                result += a[i];
                if (i != 0)
                  result += " ";
            }

        return result;
```

A more optimized way is using a `StringBuilder` since a String is immutable every time you append to it, a new instance is created - also no need for a try-catch block

Answer (score 0):

Your function return the same input, so you need to modify it, you can easily use StringBuilder class

```java
public static String reverseWord(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        builder.append(words[i]).append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString().trim();
}
```